# regex how catch urls ending with .gif

Tags: php, regex

hi i want to make a script with regex 
i need to cath all gif images urls with php . 
here is what i did

```
<?php
$subject = file_get_contents("http://www.9gag.com");
$search="^https?://(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:/[^/#?]+)+\.(?:jpg|gif|png)$";
preg_match($search, $subject, $result); 
print_r($result);
?>
```

my example is not working . i just searched stackoverflow.com read some examples but not enough i think 
thanks

1. i need to catch gif images with url's
2. i need this built with php and regex

Comment: Your regex starts with a `^` and `$` meaning the only matches will have to start and end with a URL instead of include a URL somewhere inside it.  I think this is your issue

Comment: You're missing the delimiters at the beginning and end of the regexp. Aren't you getting errors from this?

Comment: i am getting this error
Warning: preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Unknown modifier '/' in C:\wamp\www\book\9gag.php on line 10

Comment: @Barmar I will retract and downgrade my previous comment. Sure you can use a regular expression here, *but*: A) You should use a DOM parser to extract the `href` values only from relevant tag types. B) This regular expression is a mess and will break if the hostname contains a number, is an IP, if there's a non-standard port declared, and probably other ways.

Comment: @Sammitch, as I got my hands dirty trying to get a stable and correct answer to this question I was reminded (yet again) why DOM parsers are a much saner way to accomplish this.  Does PHP have something like Python's [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

Comment: @Sammitch A DOM parser is appropriate if you're extracting URLs from specific places like  src attributes. I assumed (probably incorrectly) that he was searching text for them.

Comment: @Barmar it's still problematic at best. There are plenty of sites/services that serve image URLs like `http://service.com/image.php?im=file.gif`. Then there's' the probelm of where the enclosing text begins/ends, etc, et al. I started writing a regex that *might* work for giggles, but once the debuggex diagram went off the edge of my 1920px wide monitor it became apparent that this was a losing prospect.

Comment: @Sammitch That's a problem even if you do use a DOM parser, if he wants to filter out those elements. He'll need to match the contents of the `src` attribute against the regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex starts with a ^ and $ meaning the only matches will have to start and end with a URL instead of include a URL somewhere inside it.  Try this (combining [this URL regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8234912/16959) with yours):

```
/(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)(?:(?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)(?:jpg|gif|png)/
```

or in PHP:

```
preg_match_all("/(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)(?:(?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)(?:jpg|gif|png)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

And [here is an online demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1Uo#preg_match_all) for this regex using the source code to this page (before I made this edit) (look at the `preg_match_all` tab).

Comment: i get this error
( ! ) Warning: preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Unknown modifier '/' in C:\wamp\www\book\9gag.php on line 10

Comment: @synan54 You can use any modifier use `%` instead

Comment: Updated with something that should be more helpful (and a link to a working example of it)

Comment: this makes another error
Warning: preg_match_all() [<a href='function.preg-match-all'>function.preg-match-all</a>]: Unknown modifier '(' in C:\wamp\www\book\9gag.php on line 10

Comment: You're still missing the delimiters at the beginning and end.

Comment: It should work now (added the regex delimiters and an escaped PHP example)